# Aggregate tasks in anonymous type

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've spent a few hours looking at clojurescript code, and trying to apply some of the concepts it uses to C#. I often find that I want to aggregate the results of some independent tasks in an anonymous type, that is then JSON-serialized.

I want to try to keep my code functional, so I end up writing something like this

```
return new 
 {
            A = await CallServiceA(...),
            B = await Task.WhenAll(someData.Select(Task.Factory.Create(()=>CallServiceB(....))
            C = await CallServiceC(...)
 }
```

But, it looks like the runtime will populate these properties sequentially, which means it will first populate A, then B, and then C.

Is there any way I can make the properties be populated in parallel, and still use a compact syntax like the one above, without having to declare and start the tasks separately, and await the results like so:

```
var taskA = Task.Create...
var taskB = Task.WhenAl...
var taskC = Task.Create...
 return new 
     {
                A = await taskA,
                B = await taskB,
                C = await taskC
     }
```

Comment: not an answer, but I just want to point out that in 99 % of usecases, Task.Factory.StartNew() is Wrong(tm) and Evil(tm) http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code snippet number 2 is correct and code snippet 1 is indeed sequential (except for the `WhenAll` inputs). If you want to declare tasks to be independent the way to declare that is to use form number 2.

Also remember that `await` does not start tasks. It waits for tasks that are already running.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that detail about await. It's real easy to make mistakes when playing around with the methods that produce tasks without starting them for you!

Comment: @MikaelNitell you should almost never create or use an unstarted task. The use cases for that are extremely rare. Anti-pattern.

Comment: I agree, but one of those usecases would be "playing around" :)

Comment: Correct :) Async and await are nice toys.